# jQuery drawing method using coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in Javascript/jQuery. I have a set of coordinates belonging to an area element and I am wondering if the following is possible: when I mouse over the area element, does jQuery have a method that would draw the rectangle defined by those coordinates? Or is there some library/plugin you know of that could do this?

I know I can't use the jQuery .show() method on an area element, but that is the effect I am looking for.

Comment: what have you already came up with?

Comment: here is a jsfiddle (not working, but it is my code with explanatory comments)  http://jsfiddle.net/sfs1926/wacd5bv5/16/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the jQuery offset method to translate the event.pageX and event.pageY coordinates from the event into a mouse position relative to the parent. Here's an example:

```
$("body").hover(function(e){
   var offset = $(this).offset(); 
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

   //You have your rectangle and the mouse position, Now you can check if mouse is in the area or not
   //Do something...
});
```